# Combinations within a Combination

Tags: combinations

Someone did it for me $20$ Years ago.
It was using $12$ Numbers in this example $1$ to $12$ and there were $42$ sets of $6$ numbers.

In that sample each of the $12$ numbers ONLY appears $21$ times, so this tells me it is a balanced result.

It covered the Majority of combinations and at least every combination of $4$ was presented.

I was to "believe" that in the example EG line $1-1,2,3,4,5,6$ that this was only time $1,2,3,4$ existed together.

But so does every other set of four combinations SO in LINE $1$ Many Combinations Exist $(1,2,3,5 / 1,2,3,6 / 2,3,4,5 / 2,3,4,6 ...etc)$
and I call this a set of 4, but because we are extracting 6 numbers and within those $6$ we can cover the set of $4$ combinations.
Where the normal calculation of having $12$ numbers and wanting every combination of $4$ is $495 $ Combinations.
But here we are using a string of $6$ numbers but ONLY looking at the sets of $4$ in it.
I am not sure how they got this result?
But I have a problem where I now have to have $7$ numbers...it will take more than $42$ sets

$$
1-1,2,3,4,5,6,\\
2-1,2,3,7,8,9,\\
3-1,2,3,10,11,12,\\
4-1,2,4,7,8,10,\\
5-1,2,4,9,11,12,\\
6-1,2,5,7,8,11,\\
7-1,2,5,9,10,12,\\
8-1,2,6,7,8,12,\\
9-1,2,6,9,10,11,\\
10-1,3,4,7,9,10,\\
11-1,3,4,8,11,12,\\
12-1,3,5,7,9,11,\\
13-1,3,5,8,10,12,\\
14-1,3,6,7,9,12,\\
15-1,3,6,8,10,11,\\
16-1,4,5,7,10,11,\\
17-1,4,5,8,9,12,\\
18-1,4,6,7,10,12,\\
19-1,4,6,8,9,11,\\
20-1,5,6,7,11,12,\\
21-1,5,6,8,9,10,\\
22-2,3,4,8,9,10,\\
23-2,3,4,7,11,12,\\
24-2,3,5,8,9,11,\\
25-2,3,5,7,10,12,\\
26-2,3,6,8,9,12,\\
27-2,3,6,7,10,11,\\
28-2,4,5,8,10,11,\\
29-2,4,5,7,9,12,\\
30-2,4,6,8,10,12,\\
31-2,4,6,7,9,11,\\
32-2,5,6,8,11,12,\\
33-2,5,6,7,9,10,\\
34-3,4,5,9,10,11,\\
35-3,4,5,7,8,12,\\
36-3,4,6,9,10,12,\\
37-3,4,6,7,8,11,\\
38-3,5,6,9,11,12,\\
39-3,5,6,7,8,10,\\
40-4,5,6,10,11,12,\\
41-4,5,6,7,8,9,\\
42-7,8,9,10,11,12,\\
$$